# How Can I Change Constant Array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array data but it declared with const. I am rather confused to change the data in array. Here is my array:

```
const person = {
   name: "Person A", ---> the data I want to change
   age: 100,
   favDrinks: [
     "coffee",
     "temulawak", --->> the data I want to change
     "tea"
       ],
 greeting: function() {
     console.log("Hello World"); --->> the data I want to change
   }
 }
```

How can I change the data of person.name, person.favDrinks[1], and greeting function of "Hello World". Is there a possible way to change constant data? I want to change to text strings. Here is my code :

```
function personName(nama ){
  let person.name = nama;
    person.push("name:" nama );

}

console.log(personName("Molly"));
```

But they are all wrong. Please help me. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `person` is an object, not an array.
- You can change properties values of a constant object.

**Working Demo :**

```js
const person = {
    name: "Person A",
  age: 100,
  favDrinks: [
    "coffee",
    "temulawak",
    "tea"
  ],
    greeting: function() {
    console.log("Hello World");
  }
 };
 
person.name = "Person B";
person.favDrinks[1] = "Soft Drinks";
person.greeting = function() {
    console.log('Hello Guys!');
}

console.log('updated object', person);
```

Answer (score 3):

You are doing a couple of things wrong.

1. You are pushing into an object, instead of an array.
2. You are redefining the object person by using `let` inside your function.
3. You can change properties of a const object; however, you cannot reassign it.
4. Simply add `return person`

```
const person = {
  name: "Person A",
  age: 100,
  favDrinks: ["coffee", "temulawak", "tea"],
  greeting: function () {
    console.log("Hello World");
  },
};

function personName(nama) {
  person.name = nama;
  return person;
}

console.log(personName("Molly"));
```

This is what you'll get after your changes have been made:

```
{
  name: 'Molly',
  age: 100,
  favDrinks: [ 'coffee', 'temulawak', 'tea' ],
  greeting: [Function: greeting]
}
```

Comment: okay, i will try

Comment: oh, i have next question, can you do something to push the person.name data ("Person A") with symbols change into $NAME

Comment: It is not clear what you're asking.

Comment: if i change into : 
const person = {
  name: $NAME,
  age: 100,
  favDrinks: ["coffee", "temulawak", "tea"],
  greeting: function () {
    console.log("Hello World");
  },
};
is there had possible way to change the value of the object?

Comment: I'm not sure. If you have a new question, create a new question and ask. Also, if one the answers helped you, please consider accepting and upvoting it.

Comment: okayy. anyway thank you for your help :)

Comment: but what about greetings? I do write the code : function personGreeting(sentence){
  person.greeting = function() {
    console.log(sentence);
  }
  return person;
}
console.log(personGreeting("Hello Molly")); but it return null in the console

Comment: Copy my code and play around with it. It should log correctly.

Comment: can you explain how? because I didnt found the answer. function personGreeting(sentence){
  person.greeting = [function: console.log: sentence
  ]}];
  return person;
}

Answer (score 1):

You are using let to create a variable with the name `person.name` which is not possible and then pushing it into person, in your case this is not what you should do, instead just change the values directly.

```
function personName(nama) {
    person.name = name
    return person
}

console.log(personName("Molly"));
```

if a constant variable is a string or a jumber, it cannot be changed. but if it is an array or object it cannot be changed but items in the object or array can be added, removed, or edited.

Comment: You are missing a return value.

Comment: function personGreeting(sentence){
  person.greeting = function() {
    console.log(sentence);
  }
  return person;
}
console.log(personGreeting("Hello Molly")); it returns null in the console. Why?

Answer (score 0):

I am following " Learn javascript " on Scrimba and I got into a weird situation.

I learned that `const` variables can not be reassigned and there are methods in arrays and objects where you can add or remove elements from them (e.g `arr.push()`)

```
const s = [5, 7, 2];
function editInPlace() {
    "use strict";
    s = [2, 5, 7];
}
editInPlace();
```

Console error:

```
Error: SyntaxError: unknown: "s" is read-only (/index.js:1)
```

But here comes the magic, when they assigned the const array variables new values with specific indexes then it worked well.

```
const s = [5, 7, 2];
function editInPlace() {
    "use strict";

    //s = [2, 5, 7];
    s[0] = 2;
    s[1] = 5;
    s[2] = 7;
}
editInPlace();

console.log(s)
```

Console output:

```
[2, 5, 7]
```

Now I am not able to understand why is this happening.

Looking forward to listen from you.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33404782)